# Bootstrap 3 - STATIC NAVBAR with FIXED SUBNAV...becomes sticky?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Using Bootstrap 3 here. I'm trying to make an inverted NAVBAR that is "Static" (goes up when user scrolls down) with a SUBNAV that is loaded underneath it that will become "Fixed" when it reaches the top of the screen.  If the user scrolls up again, the NAVBAR should come back. I'm not sure what you would call this.

Here's a non-working mockup of this...

http://jsbin.com/xagetaloyago/2/edit

Comment: This is almost a good example of what i'm trying to do:  http://chrishanna.info/FESubHeader.aspx    I guess we're talking about "sticky subnavs" here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this example..

http://www.bootply.com/HqtmsMHmuu

You need to use Bootstrap's affix component on your `subnav`, and update the CSS accordingly for when the `.affix` is applied to the subnav.

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom:0;
}

.subnav {
   margin:0;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1020;
  background-color: rgb(247,247,247); 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.subnav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:10;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="navtop">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
      <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav pull-right navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <form class="navbar-form">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </form>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="badge">2</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>        
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.navbar -->
</div>          

<!-- subnav here -->
<div class="navbar subnav" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container"> 
        <ul class="pager subnav-pager"> 
            <div class="btn-group-wrap">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">sub 1</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">sub 2</button>
             </div>         
        </ul>   
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.subnav').affix({
      offset: {
        top: $('#navtop').height()
      }
});
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much.  I had also found this example http://codepen.io/Matthewnie/pen/ksKbh as solution, and Sticky-elements (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) but I didn't like the way it "jumps" or "snaps" in to place. I'll use the affix method.

Comment: Seems your bootply link is broken.  =[

Comment: Seems to work for me. I added the code to the answer.

Comment: How do you make a login form inline with the buttons in the subnav? I used your code and moved a pair of login fields and a login button into the subnav but it doubled the height of the subnav bar rather than putting the login on the right side of the same line.